# Sharepoint 2010 movable webpart

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

Does anyone knows if there is a webpart which is movable?

I mean if the user have dual monitor, and in SharePoint pages I am displaying a pdf in a content-editor webpart, I want to give a option for the user to drag the webpart and place in the second monitor as a separate window. Is it possible to do so?